# PHP 5.6.8 JsonSerializable interface not found on Windows 10

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to implement the JsonSerializable interface on the class below:

```
class PostoGraduacao implements JsonSerializable
 {
    private $index;
    private $abbreviation;
    private $rank;

    public function __construct($index, $abbreviation, $rank){
        $this->index = $index;
        $this->abbreviation = $abbreviation;
        $this->rank = $rank;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return[
            'index' => $this->index,
            'abbreviation' => $this->abbreviation,
            'rank' => $this->rank
        ];
    }
}
```

My Php version:

```
C:\>php -v
PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: Apr 15 2015 15:07:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
```

And the error:

```
 Fatal error: Interface 'PostoGraduacao\Model\JsonSerializable' not found inC:\Projetos\RESTServices\src\PostoGraduacao\model\PostoGraduacao.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do:

```
class PostoGraduacao implements \JsonSerializable
```

From the error message, you can see that PHP is looking for:

```
PostoGraduacao\Model\JsonSerializable
```

This is because your class is located inside the `PostoGraduacao\Model` namespace.  Using `\JsonSerializable` tells PHP to look in the *global* namespace.

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo: No problem :)